# Django development server can't open file

Tags: python, django

I am using the djangoproject.com and I have correctly started mysite because I match them exactly with:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        _init_.py
        setting.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

But then when I try to run the development server with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It returns the error

```
MacOS/Python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I had this same problem before when trying to import django and I realized that it wasn't in pythons path so I fixed it and got it right, but when I tried doing it with this it didn't work and I'm not sure what else to try or do

Comment: In your current working directory, just do `ls manage.py` . Do you see manage.py ?

Comment: @karthikr in my case i do, but i still get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment so I reply with an answer (It's just a suggestion to try something).

Maybe try this (be sure to be in the folder where manage.py is located with your command prompt):

```
python ./manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are in the outer my site directory when you call `python manage.py runserver`. So if you ran an `ls` command, you would see manage.py and the inner mysite directory.

Comment: What do you mean by outer my site directory? Sorry I'm a beginner and not too sure what you mean by that

Comment: Note that you have two folders called mysite. The outer one would be the one that holds the other mysite folder within it.

Answer (score 0):

do one thing there are mysite directory and inside that mysite directory and manage.py file cut these both files and paste somewhere n then delete remaining mysite directoy then paste these both mysite directory n manage.py file..it will definitly work

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: yes ..i mean if you find mysite/mysite (mysite directory inside mysite directory) then if u delete one mysite directory this problem will resolve ..but remember you delete mysite directory in such a way so that all files and _pycache_ folder remains in inner mysite directory ..

Answer (score 0):

If you use virtualenvs to install django, you should move it to the folder Envs that installed Django by default. 
Using `cd` on cmd.